# Find the value of $a_4-a_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

> Let $a_1<a_2<a_3<a_4$ be positive integers such that $\sum_{i=1}^{4}\frac{1}{a_i}=\frac{11}{6}$. Find the value of $a_4-a_2.$

I do not know how to proceed. I have tried to simplify the summation but did not obtain anything useful. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

First, we establish $a_1=1$.  If $a_1\geq 2$, then $a_2\geq 3$, $a_3\geq 4$ and $a_4\geq 5$, giving
$$
\frac{11}6=\frac1{a_1}+\frac1{a_2}+\frac1{a_3}+\frac1{a_4}
\leq\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15=\frac{77}{60}
$$

Can you see how to finish from here?

Comment: I could not understand. Can you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{11}{6}=\dfrac{1}{a_1}+\dfrac{1}{a_2}+\dfrac{1}{a_3}+\dfrac{1}{a_4}
\nleq\dfrac12+\dfrac13+\dfrac14+\dfrac15=\dfrac{77}{60} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a_1=1$

$\dfrac{5}{6}=\dfrac{1}{a_2}+\dfrac{1}{a_3}+\dfrac{1}{a_4}
\nleq\dfrac13+\dfrac14+\dfrac15=\dfrac{47}{60} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a_2=2$

$\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{1}{a_3}+\dfrac{1}{a_4} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a_3 a_4=3(a_3+a_4)$

In positive integers solutions of last equation is only $(4,12),(12,4),(6,6)$.

$a_3<a_4 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (a_3,a_4)=(4,12)$.

$a_4-a_2=10$

Comment: How does the first inequality imply $a_1=1$?

Comment: @MrAP. Any other not possible, only $\dfrac{11}{6}<\dfrac11+\dfrac12+\dfrac13+\dfrac14=\dfrac{25}{12}$ and  $\dfrac{11}{6}>\dfrac11+\dfrac1k+\dfrac1m+\dfrac1n$ for any $1<k<m<n$.

Comment: I am sorry but I still cannot understand. It is going above my head. Why did you take $2, 3, 4, 5$ ? There are many other combinations which you could have taken. And the $a_1=1$ part I still do not understand.

Comment: Let $z=\frac{11}{6}\approx 1.83333$. $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{25}{12}\approx 2.08333>z$. $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{77}{60}\approx 1.28333<z$. $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{67}{60}\approx 1.11667<\frac{77}{60}<z$. It means that first fraction as $\frac{1}{2}$ is not valid, need only $\frac{1}{1}$, i.e. $a_1=1$.